# Why is NaCL disabled for Chromium?

Tags: 11.10, chromium

I would like to test NaCL with the Chromium I installed from the software center, however it seems to have been disabled for an unclear reason.

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/show/378128

> [ Fabien Tassin ]
>     * Disable NaCl until we figure out what to do with the private toolchain
>     - update debian/rules

Is anyone aware what this means and how it came to be that this was reason for disabling NaCL for the base, the updates and even daily builds?

Comment: Is this still the case in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Chromium 16, there are currently build issues with NaCl on Ubuntu. I believe this has something to do with compiling Chromium with the Debian security [hardening wrapper](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/HardeningWrapper). A bunch of launchpad bugs have been filed semi-related to this, but I think [LP#882942](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/882942) is the main one triaged to NaCl on Chromium.

Unfortunately this means if you want to use NaCl in Ubuntu, you must install the official [Google Chrome build](https://www.google.com/chrome/).

Comment: perfect! works on 14.04! I use it only for nacl stuff thx!